# Is it possible to share internet connection in Windows 10 by anything other than ICS

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing

This question has been asked quite a lot but I haven't managed to get it working with any of the things I found

So, I am trying to use the route command or something similar to share my internet connection manually from my Wi-Fi to my LAN cause whenever I trying to use the normal share option it just messes up everything with my LAN and it's pretty annoying

Wi-Fi: (Android phone)

IPv4 Address: 192.168.43.2
IPv4 Gateway: 192.168.43.1

LAN: (Not any router the IP been manually set by me)

IPv4 Address: 192.168.1.2

Comment: I'm pretty sure, whatever is messing up your wifi when you share normally is also stopping you from using route to share the connection. It sounds like you are trying to solve a problem, come up with the solution and now are stuck with that (classical X-Y problem). You may want to consider asking for help solving the actual problem, because our combined technical knowledge may be able to provide answers you did not consider.

Comment: @LPChip its not preventing me from using window 10's option to share my connection it just messes with my LAN IPv4 setting and it doesn't restore it properly when i turn off sharing

Answer (score 0):

No. Route modifies the routing table for how to send packets. It does not puck up packets off the lLAN or forward them.

Comment: Is there anything else than route to use to do that?

Comment: You should seriously consider @LPChip advice. What router are you using and what happens when you use the more common mode of the WIFI and LAN bridged together?

Comment: Well I don't use a router I use my phone which is an android device also the bridge option doesn't work at all it just fails not sure why

Comment: Please explain your setup better - as its currently not at all clear. If (pretending for a moment that an Android phone is not a router) you don't have a router, what are you bridging?   Are you trying to share your phones Internet with your PC, and then bridge that onto your LAN?  If so, where does 192.168.1.2 come from?

Comment: Well I just updated my question hope it makes things clearer the thing is I don't understand this it's simple to do this in Linux why I can't do that on Windows